# Display all traits for a variable

Tags: debugging, rust

I am looking for tools to make debugging easier with Rust.  One tool that would be very useful is one that showed all functions for all traits for a given type.  Ideally, this would be a macro or function that I could insert in my code to assist with debugging.  In other words, at run-time (assuming debug symbols are present), given a variable, I want to display everything about it:  it's attributes, value, traits along with a list of all functions for each trait, etc...

I would like a macro or function that takes any Rust type and returns a string with a prettified tree of traits and all function names for each trait.

Using code from: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/trait.html

```
let mut dolly: Sheep = Animal::new("Dolly");

show_all_traits(dolly);
```

should display:

```
Animal
    fn new(name: &'static str) -> Self;
    fn name(&self) -> &'static str;
    fn noise(&self) -> &'static str;
    fn talk(&self);
Sheep
    fn is_naked(&self) -> bool;
    fn shear(&mut self);
```

Comment: Your IDE already gives you all methods for `dolly` if you simply type `dolly.`. I've got a hard time understanding why you first want to compile and run your program to get this information. That seems strictly worse than what you get from the IDE.

Comment: The Rust analyzer in VS Code is slow, buggy and incomplete so you often cannot do that.  I've also tried IDEA and while it was more stable, it often didn't work.

Comment: I'm using Rust Analyzer as well. It's very fast for me, except for the initial one-time compilation for a crate, and I rarely hit a bug. In particular in the last year it has been amazing. I wonder what I'm doing differently. :)

Comment: I am working on a very large project.  That could be the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't (and probably couldn't without compiler intrinsic) possible. However documentation generated by cargo includes sections *Trait Implementations*, *Auto Trait Implementations* and *Blanket Implementations* that will list all traits implemented for given type.

Comment: In other languages, you can use reflection to get type information at run-time.  I am looking to see how to accomplish this in Rust.

Comment: @RobertLaFerla There is no such thing as reflection in Rust. Rust doesn't have it's own runtime (technically it does, but it's similar to C's).

Comment: @RobertLaFerla What do you even want to accomplish? This seems to me like a [xyproblem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: No, this is not a xyproblem.  This is a question about how to improve debugging at runtime.  Given Rust's design, this approach is not possible.

Comment: Side note:  Here are a few interesting reflection projects but likely won't address my question:  https://docs.rs/reflect/latest/reflect, https://www.osohq.com/post/rust-reflection-pt-1 and https://github.com/Diggsey/query_interface